# All unique multiplication products

Tags: matlab, vector

I'd like to obtain all *unique* products for a given vector.

For example, given `a`:

```
a = [4,10,12,3,6]
```

I want to obtain a matrix that contains the results of:

```
4*10
4*12
4*3
4*6
10*12
10*3
10*6
12*3
12*6
3*6
```

Is there a short and/or quick way of doing this in MATLAB?

**EDIT**: `a` may contain duplicate numbers, giving duplicate products - and these must be kept.

Comment: What does "unique" mean to you if you're keeping duplicate products from duplicate numbers?

Comment: All unique pairwise combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
a =

    4   10   12    3    6
```

Construct the matrix of *all* pairwise products:

```
>> all_products = a .* a.'
all_products =

    16    40    48    12    24
    40   100   120    30    60
    48   120   144    36    72
    12    30    36     9    18
    24    60    72    18    36
```

Now, construct a mask to keep only those values below the main diagonal:

```
>> mask = tril(true(size(all_products)), -1)
mask =

  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0
```

and apply the mask to the product matrix:

```
>> unique_products = all_products(mask)
unique_products =

    40
    48
    12
    24
   120
    30
    60
    36
    72
    18
```

Comment: I just learned about [`squareform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html), might be useful here instead of `tril` + indexing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hm, I didn't know you could use `squareform` to go back to the vector form, but it looks like you still have to zero out the diagonal. Pretty much the same number of steps, but I think this more generic.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can abuse [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html), which considers only one of the two possible orders for each pair:

```
result = pdist(a(:), @times);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option involves [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), which returns all combinations of `k` elements out of a vector, each row is one combination. `prod` computes the product of rows or columns:

```
a = [4,10,12,3,6];
b = nchoosek(a,2);
b = prod(b,2); % 2 indicates rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this. Have the unique function filter out the result of multiplying a by itself.

```
b = unique(a*a')
```

Comment: If `a` is a row vector as in OP, this product yields a scalar (it’s the dot product). Also, `'` is the complex conjugate transpose, better use `.'` to change the orientation of a vector.